# How to mock objects in Golang 1.19 for testing purposes?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, interface, mocking

I'm writing a client built on top of a [mongo.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client) from the "mongo" package. Because of the nature of mongo client which requires a live database connection, I've decided to try the mocking approach, that is, to store an interface with a set of methods (which also return the interfaces) I would use on the mongo client.

The issue is that the return type of some mongo functions doesn't implement my interfaces for a reason which I do not understand.

For example, [mongo.Collection](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection) doesn't implement my `ICollection` interface, however, the [mongo.SingleResult](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#SingleResult) does implement the `ISingleResult` interface:

```golang
type ICollection interface {
    FindOne(context.Context, interface{}, ...*options.FindOneOptions) ISingleResult
}

type ISingleResult interface {
    Decode(v interface{}) error
}
```

The issue is gone if I change the return type from `ISingleResult` to `*mongo.SingleResult`, but this is not what I want, because I could not control the `*mongo.SingleResult` logic and track its calls as I could do with its mock.

Please help me to fix that logic or provide another testing approach which is more common if my is wrong.

Comment: Your `ICollection.FindOne` has a return type of `ISingleResult`. That is not the return type of `mongo.Collection.FindOne`, so it does not implement that interface. Method signatures must match *exactly*. Your options are: have your mock return a `mongo.SingleResult` you create yourself, or wrap `mongo.Collection` in a type whose method signatures you can control.

Comment: The first option doesn't work for me, as the returned object might have functions which could return another mongo object which could eventually lead to the live connection dependency again. The second seems like a solution, but I woukd need to wrap every single mongo object I am going to use.

Comment: Correct. Personally my preferred approach is to write a DB layer that handles all database activity, and mock that. When I want to test the interaction with Mongo specifically, I do so with an integration test (connecting to a real test instance of Mongo) rather than using mocks, since mocking away the database isn't going to test most of what you care about in the database layer.